Highchart data series cut off at the max at (at the top)
I am using Highchart, with areaspline chart type.
The object settings object looks like that:
{
    "responsive": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "condition": {
                    "maxWidth": 500
                },
                "_id": "highcharts-gxusaxl-69"
            }
        ]
    },
    "chart": {
        "type": "areaspline",
        "style": {
            "cursor": "pointer"
        }
    },
    "title": {},
    "subtitle": {},
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "lineWidth": 1,
        "lineColor": "#d2d8db",
        "labels": {
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
                "fontWeight": "400",
                "fontSize": "0.75rem",
                "color": "#3f5c69"
            }
        },
        "crosshair": {
            "width": 1,
            "color": "#000000",
            "dashStyle": "ShortDash",
            "zIndex": 3
        },
        "type": "datetime"
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "labels": {
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
                "fontWeight": "400",
                "fontSize": "0.75rem",
                "color": "#3f5c69"
            },
            "format": "{value}%"
        },
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "min": 0,
        "max": 100
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "top",
        "layout": "horizontal",
        "itemStyle": {
            "fontWeight": "400",
            "fontSize": "0.75rem",
            "color": "#333",
            "fontFamily": "Open Sans"
        },
        "useHTML": true
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "stacking": "percent",
            "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": false,
                "format": "{point.percentage:.0f}%"
            }
        },
        "area": {
            "stacking": "percent",
            "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": false,
                "format": "{point.percentage:.0f}%"
            },
            "marker": {
                "enabled": false,
                "symbol": "circle"
            }
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "id": "asIs",
            "name": "As is",
            "color": "#27caff1a",
            "type": "areaspline",
            "data": [
                [1704060000000, 0],
                [1704146400000, 44],
                [1704232800000, 38]
            ],
            "lineColor": "#27CAFF",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "marker": {
                "enabled": false,
                "symbol": "circle"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "modified",
            "name": "Modified",
            "color": "#c61d4d1a",
            "type": "areaspline",
            "data": [
                [1704060000000, 0],
                [1704146400000, 114],
                [1704232800000, 117]
            ],
            "lineColor": "#C61D4D",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "marker": {
                "enabled": false,
                "symbol": "circle"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "ignored",
            "name": "Ignored",
            "color": "#F8C00A1A",
            "type": "areaspline",
            "data": [
                [1704060000000, 0],
                [1704146400000, 42],
                [1704232800000, 45]
            ],
            "lineColor": "#F8C00A",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "marker": {
                "enabled": false,
                "symbol": "circle"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "averageSimilarity",
            "name": "Adherence",
            "color": "#2d96d2",
            "type": "spline",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "dashStyle": "LongDash",
            "marker": {
                "enabled": false,
                "symbol": "circle"
            },
            "data": [
                [1704060000000, 0],
                [1704146400000, 50.710857],
                [1704232800000, 48.705587]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "exporting": {
        "buttons": {
            "contextButton": {
                "enabled": false
            }
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "resolution": "Day"
    }
}

My problem is that the data series is cut off at the top.
as you can see here:
check the chart photo here
It's important for me that the yAxis will be between 0% to 100%
and that I will be able to see al the data.
On my case the data is exceeding and rises up more than 100%.

The reason behind this behaviour is that the y-axis extremes are numeric values and not percentage, meaning that you are actually setting extrems of 0 to 100, not from 0% to 100%.You can either adjust your data set to fit into the 0-100 range or format y-axis labels using labels.formatter(), so that the y-axis labels actually show the percentage range of 0% to 100%.
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            const range = this.axis.max - this.axis.min;
            const valueInPercent = ((this.value - this.axis.min) / range) * 100;
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(valueInPercent, 0) + '%';
        }
    }
}

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/54f9ytco/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter
